# Error al cargar que me está dando dolor de cabeza

Tags: php

me genera error a la hora de iniciar en el localhost, he revisado el código pero no veo el error, también busque el foros pero no me sale nada [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi codigo del controllers

```php
    
class Controllers
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->views = new Views();
        $this->loadModel();
    }

    public function loadModel()
    {
        //HomeModel.php
        $model = get_class($this)."Model";
        $routClass = "Models/".$model.".php";
        if(file_exists($routClass)){
            require_once($routClass);
            $this->model = new $model();
        }
    }
}
```

Les agradezco de ante mano...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aunque no indicas la versión de PHP que estas utilizando, por el error que tienes imagino que es la versión 8.2. En esa versión la creación de propiedades dinámicas es obsoleta (ya no es posible usarla). La creación de propiedades dinámicas ocurre cuando una clase asigna propiedades en el constructor y estas propiedades no están declaradas ni en la clase ni en una clase padre.

Una solución es usar *#[\AllowDynamicProperties]* justo antes de la definición de la clase:

```
#[\AllowDynamicProperties]
class Controllers {
    ...
}
```

Más información y otras formas de solucionar tu problema en https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration82.deprecated.php